# Express async post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

## My Code

My code in the backend will get the post data and call a async function

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
   var mail = decodeURIComponent(req.body.mail), password;
   await bcrypt.hash(decodeURIComponent(req.body.password), saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
       ...
   });
});
```

## Problem

If I want to start the application I get this warning:

> [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is depre

is there a better solution?

## EDIT

I got the same warning if I just do this, but I am not sure how can I make a callback here.

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res) => { res.json({ success: true }); });
```

Comment: you don't need to pass a callback function to `hash` method if you are using the `async` keyword. `await bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds)`. If the error still there, add the callback to the controller `async (req, res, next) => {`

Comment: I am sure that you do not have to do any URL-decoding. All the values in `req.body` are already decoded. Doing this will cause errors.

Comment: Make sure to always wrap `await` in try/catch : `app.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => { try { await ... } catch (e) { next(e); } });` [see](https://medium.com/@Abazhenov/using-async-await-in-express-with-node-8-b8af872c0016#3299)

Comment: Why are you using await?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bcrypt` ([this one](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js), right?) is not a promisified library.

You cannot `await` its functions.

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, saltRounds, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      // error
      return;
    }
    // success
  });
});
```

But you can [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) it if you want.

```
const util = require('util');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const hashAsync = util.promisify(bcrypt.hash);

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  hashAsync(req.body.password, saltRounds).then(result => {
    // success
  }).catch(err => {
    // error
  });
});
```

Of course the above can be written as `async`/`await`, too. Don't forget the `try`/`catch`, though.

Also, I am sure that you do not have to do any URL-decoding. All the values in `req.body` are already decoded. Calling `decodeURIComponent()` yourself means you will end up decoding the values *twice*. This will cause errors as soon as the value *actually* contains something like `%xx` somewhere - especially in passwords this will occur sooner or later.

Comment: Now I am *really* curious as to why this was downvoted.

Comment: I don't see how it addresses the question. It has indicated that the problem happens both with and without bcrypt.

Comment: Your own comment under the question basically mentions the exact same as this answer, so I don't quite get what your point is. Maybe we should wait until the OP tries the code?

Comment: well, no, i think the op has a mis-understanding of where `async` is appropriate. see the last example, where there's no await and async is still being used. your answer doesn't address that at all.

Comment: Yeah, the OP's misconception is that he can somehow `await` callback-taking functions, and in order to use `await` in a function he as learned that the function itself must be prefixed by `async` for some reason. He copied that off of somewhere without really understanding it. How does this make my answer incorrect? And how does that facilitate a downvote on the question (if that was your's as well, which I think it was).

Comment: i never said it was incorrect. i find it not useful.

Comment: It solves the problem. It explains the reason for the error. It shows an alternative. Your definition of "not useful" is *way* off. But indulge me, what would have been "useful" in your book?

Comment: @KevinB Nothing, huh? How odd.

Comment: You have said "I find it not useful" and claimed it wouldn't "address the question". I can't do a lot about you finding it "not useful", but your claim is nonsense.